# IdentityServer on MVC : What is Audience refering in AddJwtBearer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microservices, identityserver4, audience

I already have the access token working with my application in my api gateway.

```
var identityUrl = Configuration.GetValue<string>("urls:identity");
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityUrlExternal");
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Audience = "api1";              
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
```

What is the audience option in `AddJwtBearer` referring to?  Is that refer to `ClientId` or the `ApiScope`? At the moment, I was based on the scope of my mobile application setup to communicate with the API gateway. If I changed to something e.g. a client id sent from mobile (`ro.client`), the authorized API function will not be able access it.

I would like to get a clear understand is my setting correct.

In addition, how do add Authorized Scope in the ASP.net MVC core project under the controller?

Comment: I think IdentityServer4 documentation is obvious  http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/apis.html

Comment: Sorry I think I missed that part of my reading. Thanks

Comment: I don't think its obvious. What is the name of an API resource?

Comment: That link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 3):

The following link will take you to the explanation:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html

> The ApiName property checks if the token has a matching audience (or short aud) claim.
>
> In IdentityServer you can also sub-divide APIs into multiple scopes. If you need that granularity you can use the ASP.NET Core authorization policy system to check for scopes.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. This docs explain further: "When using the scope-only model, no aud (audience) claim will be added to the token since this concept does not apply. If you need an aud claim, you can enable the EmitStaticAudienceClaim setting on the options. " and also "...all the requested scope and audience combination get merged into a single access token". So, the answer is: "aud" is a claim with similar functions as scopes and for the same purposes. Choice of scopes and/or aud claims seems more depends on a client or have historical reasons, rather has security implications

Answer (score 1):

An audience is a unique identifier for an issued token.  The audience value could be either the client id for an id token or an API for an access token.

In your project, you can communicate with *api1* by adding it to the scope of your application.